# Ajax call in datepicker with selected date jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, fosjsroutingbundle

I am building Monthpicker. How to make ajax call inside datepicker?

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date('2013'),
        maxDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm",
        onClose: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: Routing.generate('ajax_table', $this)
            })
        }
    });
});
```

How to pass selected values in `onClose`? I want to render a table after ajax call. I am using fos_routing.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date('2013'),
        maxDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $.ajax({
                url: Routing.generate('ajax_table', {selectedDate: selectedDate})
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But I can't result of `console.log(selectDate)` inside `onClose` to text how my parameter will look like.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose, Jquery UI DatePicker onClose event has 2 arguments.
dateText and datepicker Instance.

You can use dateText for your ajax call. I hope this will help.